# React - undefined variable when using concatenated variables

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to run `convertAddress` on `setAddress` by concatenating three separate props into one string however I receive an error that `isoCode` is not defined.

The console returns `Simcoe,Ontario,Canada` for `setAddress` however, the code only works when passing the location as string. This means there is an issue with `setAddress` because the console for `setAddress`returns the exact same string I used for `test`. Why does `convertAddress` work on `test` and not `setAddress`?

```
  const test = 'Simcoe,Ontario,Canada';
  const address = test ? convertAddress(test) : '';
```

from console:

```
  console.log(setAddress + ' setAddress');
  console.log(test + ' test');
  console.log(address + ' result');
```

[image]

Original code using setAddress:

```
export function convertAddress(myAddress) {
  const split = myAddress.split(',');

  const countryName = Country.getAllCountries().filter(
    (c) => c.name === split[split.length - 1].replace(' ', '')
  );

  const resultStateProvince = split[split.length - 2];

  const state = State.getStatesOfCountry(countryName[0].isoCode).filter((s) =>
    resultStateProvince.includes(s.name)
  );
  return `${split[split.length - 3]}${state.length > 0 ? `, ${state[0].isoCode}` : ''}`;
}
       
 const setAddress =
        organizationDetails?.cityDetails?.city +
        ',' +
        organizationDetails?.stateDetails?.state +
        ',' +
        organizationDetails?.countryDetails?.country;
    
      const address = setAddress ? convertAddress(setAddress) : '';
    ...
    <span>{address}</span>
```

[image]

Comment: this is because either `State.getStatesOfCountry` does not match any country or subsequent `.filter((s) => ...)` filters all things out.

Comment: @skyboyer I updated the question to confirm the data for `setAddress` fetches properly with matches in getStatesofCountry. I think there is a problem with the `address` function

Comment: did you try to debug with step by step execution?

Comment: @skyboyer I updated the question with my debugging. Using a string works so there is an issue with `setAddress` not being ready as a string?

Comment: You are definitely accessing some value from an empty array.  You have `countryName[0].isoCode` and `state[0].isoCode`, so the error means that either `countryName` or `state` is an empty array.  Some console logging can help you figure out which address in your data set is missing properties.  You've got a lot of `?.` implying that certain properties are optional on your `organizationDetails` object, but your `convertAddress` function is expecting all to be present.

Comment: @LindaPaiste why does the code work with the string `test` and not for `setAddress` when they are the same per the console?

Comment: Where are the external variables `Country` and `State` defined?  Is it possible that `Country.getAllCountries()` and `State.getStatesOfCountry()` might return different data depending on how and where in the code you are calling the `convertAddress` function?

Comment: Pulling from here: https://github.com/harpreetkhalsagtbit/country-state-city#readme

Comment: Hmmm...that should have consistent data so that's not it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250780/discussion-between-linda-paiste-and-kyle-underhill).

Answer (score 1):

If the function works as you expected with the string `test`, then the maybe one possible solution would be looking into the `setAdress` variable.

You split the address string, use the last element, which is country name, filter it, and then use `countryName[0]` to get the first country name. Simply, the `countryName[0]` doesn't exist, that is why you see "isoCode" is undefined.

There's no clue where the `organizationDetails` comes from; therefore, you need to show us more codes so that others can debug in depth.

I personally recommend you use TypeScript so that you can catch errors on the compile-time level.

One thing I can possibly guess is that the optional chainings you used in `setAddress`. If there's nothing found, then it will return `undefined` and it can cause the type errors you see. Use type guard so that it won't return `undefined` as it is not a good approach.

type guard example using [Nullish coalescing operator(??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing)

```js
const city = organizationDetails?.cityDetails?.city ?? '';
const state = organizationDetails?.cityDetails?.state ?? '';
const country = organizationDetails?.cityDetails?.country ?? '';

const setAddress = `${city}, ${state}, ${country}`;
```

then, at least, undefined won't appear.

Lastly, when you split a string that has names separated by commas, then use `trim()` not to have empty spaces. (if you are not sure if the split items have spaces)

Answer (score 0):

1. Trim your data before you use it, and if you're using specific spots, grab them

```js
let [ rawCountry, rawState, rawCity, ...other ] = myAddress.split(',').map(v => v.trim()).reverse()
rawCountry = rawCountry.replace(/\s+/g, " ")
rawState = rawState.replace(/\s+/g, " ")
```

2. use [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), not [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
const country = Country.getAllCountries().find(
  target => target.name === unknownCountry
)
```

Find returns the first result found and exits the loop early. Filter returns *all* matches that pass the filter test

3. You're not validating your input whatsoever. checking that either the country *or* state is found, you can either throw an error, or return a value early

```js
if(!rawCity || !rawState || !rawCountry) throw new Error("City, State, and Country are Required Values")
```

```js
if(!country) throw new Error("Country Not Found")
```

```js
if(!state) throw new Error("State Not Found")
```

4. what about uppercase and lowercase values? you're not normalizing the data whatsoever. this is really not going to be any more helpful as a function than just passing through the data.

```js
const country = Country.getAllCountries().find(
  target => new RegExp(`^${target.name}$`, 'i').test(unknownCountry)
)
```

5. This is just my personal advice, but if you ever need to use semi-colons in JS, you're doing something wrong in your formatting, and there's almost always a different more canonical way to write that statement. there are only a few very specific cases where they're actually needed

#### Putting It All Together

```js
const Country = {
  getAllCountries() {
    return [
      { name: "United States", isoCode: "USA", provinces: [{ name: "Nevada", isoCode: "NV" }, { name: "South Carolina", isoCode: "SC"}] },
      { name: "Canada", isoCode: "CAN", provinces: [{ name: "Alberta", isoCode: "AB" }, { name: "Ontario", isoCode: "ON"}, { name: "Nova Scotia", isoCode: "NS"},] },
      { name: "United Kingdom", isoCode: "GBR", provinces: [{ name: "Essex", isoCode: "ESS" }]},
    ]
  }
}

const State = {
  getStatesOfCountry(country) {
    return country.provinces
  }
}

function convertAddress(myAddress) {
  let [ rawCountry, rawState, rawCity, ...other ] = myAddress.split(',').map(v => v.trim()).reverse()
  
  if(!rawCity || !rawState || !rawCountry) throw new Error("City, State, and Country are Required Values")
  
  rawState = rawState.replace(/\s+/g, " ")
  rawCountry = rawCountry.replace(/\s+/g, " ")

  const country = Country.getAllCountries().find(
    target =>
      new RegExp(`^${target.name}$`, 'i').test(rawCountry)
      || target.isoCode === rawCountry.toUpperCase()
  )
  if(!country) throw new Error("Country Not Found")

  const state = State.getStatesOfCountry(country).find(
    target => new RegExp(target.name, 'i').test(rawState)
  )

  const stateString = state?.isoCode ? `, ${state.isoCode}` : ""

  return `${rawCity}${stateString}`
}

const testValues = [
  "Test , Ontario , CAN ",
  "some city,alberta,canada",
  "some city,nova   sCoTia ,  canada ",
  "some city,South carolina,USA ",
  "some city,South carolina,GBR ",
  "some city",
  "some city,CAN",
  "some city, North Chungcheong, South Korea",
]

testValues.forEach(val => {
  try {
    const newVal = convertAddress(val)
    console.log(`'${val}' => '${newVal}'`)
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(`Could Not Convert '${val}' => '${err.message}'`)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I find myself wanting more context about when and how and where these tests are running. But here's what I think is happening:

`setAddress` is based on a snapshot of the value of `organizationDetails` *at the point when your code file was run*, when im guessing it was `null` or `undefined`, so it's probably set to `",,"`

But in the context when you run this test:

```
console.log(setAddress + ' setAddress');
console.log(test + ' test');
console.log(address + ' result');
```

Then i'm guessing your code was loaded when `organizationDetails` *was* set, and so it's seting itself correctly, to `"Simcoe,Onatario,Canada"`

In fact i'm guessing if you add an extra line to your test, it will work (because of the context that you are running it in):

```
console.log(setAddress + ' setAddress');
console.log(test + ' test');
console.log(address + ' result');
console.log(convertAddress(setAddress) + ' setAddress result');
```

If my hunch is right, then it's about exploring why `organizationDetails` was not set in the context that your code is run in react.

Answer (score 0):

The answers above seem helpful and close to the answer but i will provide an answer as well to contribute a bit.
In a comment it was mentioned you are using this [country-state-city library](https://github.com/harpreetkhalsagtbit/country-state-city).
While i don't know the context within which you are using it, i noticed that inside some files([example](https://github.com/harpreetkhalsagtbit/country-state-city/tree/develop/data/Afghanistan-AF/Badakhshan-BDS)) there is no isoCode, so it might be useful to console.log everything that might be in that countryName[0] value. if some values don't have the isoCode property you might need first to filter them out and then do your thing.
Something that will probably also be helpful is this(here->obj = {hello:"world"}).
When evaluated as boolean str3 is true. Any more context will be helpful to answer the question more appropriately(also my intuition tells me it is most likely not related to react,if it is though, the whole component has to be provided).
[image]